# Hash map of multiple values

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, hash, collections

I have a hash map of multiple values with the same key. I am looking for selecting a particular value of any index specified in a for loop and return the value. I have done the following but it is giving me errors **Index out of bounds for length**:
event_actor is the key, x is the index of the values in a list

public static Message SelectReceivedMsg(int event_actor, double recv_time) {

```
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < mBuffer.get(event_actor).size(); x++) {
        if ((mBuffer.get(event_actor).get(x).getMsg_flag().equals("Tx")) && (mBuffer.get(event_actor).get(x).getMsg_Recvtime() == recv_time)) {
             mBuffer.get(event_actor).get(x);// get m from the received mBuffer
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        if (mBuffer.get(event_actor).get(x)==null) break;
    }
    return mBuffer.get(event_actor).get(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` in Java - implementation of [Associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) and can't have two duplicate keys.

Maybe you need `List<Pair<Integer, Object>>`?

Comment: thank you @Chuyasov, but Java does not support associative arrays

Comment: @Agbako are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

Consider your `for` statement :

```
  for (x = 0; x < mBuffer.get(event_actor).size(); x++) {
```

If and when that loop completes “normally” (ie without hitting the `break` statements), then the value of `x` will be == `mBuffer.get(event_actor).size()` - in other words, 1 greater than the maximum index of `mBuffer.get(event_actor)`.

So when the first thing you do after that loop is :

```
  return mBuffer.get(event_actor).get(x);
```

That x will be beyond the maximum index (ie “out of bounds”)

Something else caught my eye :  It is good that you are testing for null with :

```
  if (mBuffer.get(event_actor).get(x)==null) break;
```

However, you want to move that check to BEFORE the first `if` :

```
  if ((mBuffer.get(event_actor).get(x).getMsg_flag().equals("Tx")) && …
```

Because that first `if` will be throwing the NullPointerException if that value is null before your second ‘`if`` checks for it !

Comment: Thank you @racraman, please, what do I do about the for loop to incorporate your observation.